# Efficient difference between two progress queries

Tags: openedge, progress-db

Can anyone explain me why when a I run a query in Progress that acts only on one table it runs just in seconds and when I run a query acting on multiple tables it runs in hours. Is there any wrong thing that I'm using?

My last attempt was this:

```
FOR EACH multipos.mp_loja NO-LOCK,
    EACH multipos.mp_acmp NO-LOCK,
    EACH multipos.mp_mvlj NO-LOCK

    WHERE mp_mvlj.lj_cod    = mp_loja.lj_cod 
      AND mp_mvlj.mvl_dtmov =  mp_acmp.mvl_dtmov:

           /* EXPORT ... */

END.
```

By now, i changed it to this:

```
    FOR EACH multipos.mp_mvlj NO-LOCK WHERE mp_mvlj.mvl_dtmov = 04/20/2015,
    EACH multipos.mp_loja NO-LOCK WHERE mp_loja.lj_cod = mp_mvlj.lj_cod,
    EACH multipos.mp_acmp NO-LOCK WHERE mp_acmp.lj_cod = mp_mvlj.lj_cod 
                                    AND mp_acmp.mvl_dtmov = mp_mvlj.mvl_dtmov:

    /* EXPORT */

END.
```

Is this, now, the most efficient way ?

Comment: How may records does each of the tables have?

Comment: One of them almost 200.000. Crossing them would be only those 200.000 with one more column

Comment: For a question like this it would be good to include the exact table layouts with fields and indices. It's easy to create a .df-file using the data administration tool.

Answer (score 2):

You have no criteria specified to join mp_loja to mp_acmp.

**It is all about the indexes that are available and the WHERE clauses that invoke them.  For good performance you MUST use fields which are leading components of indexes.  Anything less will result in table scans.**

Compile your code with XREF.  You will see WHOLE-INDEX in the output.  That means you are executing table scans.  If you scan a whole table with each iteration of a join it is going to be very, very painful.  If you do that two levels deep it will be utterly ridiculous.

It is extremely important that the fields in WHERE clauses be the **leading** component (or the only component) of an index in the table being selected.  Otherwise Progress cannot bracket the query and will have to do a table scan to evaluate the condition.

Ideally you have a unique index on the mp_mvlj table with lj_cod and mvl_dtmov as the only fields.

You also need a unique index that joins mp_loja to mp_acmp.

Carefully review the WHERE clauses and the indexes available.  If there is no suitable index you may need to add one.

Your current code is the equivalent of 3 nested FOR EACH loops:

```
for each mp_loja no-lock:  /* no WHERE, scan the entire table */

  for each mp_acmp no-lock:  /* no WHERE, scan the entire table ON EVERY ITERATION of the outer loop which is scanning it's entire table!!! */

    for each mp_mvlj no-lock
      where mp_mvlj.lj_cod    = mp_loja.lj_cod 
        and mp_mvlj.mvl_dtmov =  mp_acmp.mvl_dtmov:  /* WHERE of unknown quality, but we are executing it on every iteration of the two outer loops */

      /* export ... */

    end.

  end.

end.
```

I you do not believe me try an experiment with the "sports2000" database.  In my copy of it there are 3,948 order records and 13,970 orderline records.

```
define variable i as integer no-undo.

for each order no-lock,
    each orderline no-lock:

  i = i + 1.

end.

display i.
```

I get i = 55,153,560.  Which just happens to be 3,948 * 13,970.  It takes a **very** long time to execute.

Contrast that with:

```
define variable i as integer no-undo.
for each order no-lock,
    each orderline no-lock where orderline.ordernum = order.ordernum:

  i = i + 1.

end.

display i.
```

Much, much faster.  i = 13,942  (there are 28 orphaned orderlines in my copy of sports2000...)

Comment: I'm joining each record of table 1 with only one of table 2 through the condition " table1.atrr2 = table2.atrr1 ".

Comment: there is no condition to the left of AND

Comment: Also - table2.attr1 needs to be the leading component of an index to avoid a table scan.

Comment: Ok i do understand your though but if i want to join mp_acmp and mp_loja with mp_mvlj shouldn't i only connect mp_acmp to mp_mvlj and mp_loja to mp_mvlj  separately ?

Comment: I have no idea what your database is like -- I do not know how many records each table has nor what the available indexes are.  Nor do I know if you really need all 3 layers or if the order that you have nested them makes any sense.  Only you know that.  Think about how you would make each of the queries efficient.  Each step of the process must follow the rules.